# JQuery UI Sortable: drop over an existing element on list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Im trying to create an example similar to the  classic Jquery UI sortable Example:

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default

The default behaviour is that each element on the list changes its ordinal depending if it's placed above or below a given element.

```
ordinal:1---X
ordinal:2---Y
ordinal:3---Z
ordinal:4:--W
```

If a move X below Z I get this result:

```
ordinal:1---Y
ordinal:2---Z
ordinal:3---X
ordinal:4:--W
```

What I would like to accomplish is to get to be able to drop an element on top of another in order to make it get the same ordinal. For example if I dropped X above Z instead of below Z I would get this:

```
ordinal:1---Y
ordinal:2---Z
ordinal:2---X
ordinal:3:--W
```

Is there any way Ui's sortable can help me achieve this?

Thanks a lot!